# Как определить тип переменной в с++, а именно он ссылочный или нет, для шаблонной функции?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, шаблоны-с++

Нужно определить тип переменной в с++, а именно он ссылочный или нет, для шаблонной функции.

Comment: [`std::is_reference<T>::value`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_reference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Стандартно - как сказали в коимментарии,

```
std::is_reference<T>::value
```

А самому написать - типа

```
template<typename T>
struct isRef
{
    static const bool value = false;
};

template<typename T>
struct isRef<T&>
{
    static const bool value = true;
};
```